# convert float to short with minimal loss of precision

Tags: java, floating-point, short

I have this sine wave which generates floating point values (e.g. 0.37885) but I want them as shorts. Direct casting with short gives me a value of 0. so what is the solution?

Can anyone tell me how to do it - ideally without loss of precision - or minimal loss of precision if this is all that is possible?

Comment: The size of `float` is typically 4 bytes, and the size of `short` is typically 2 bytes. How exactly are you hoping to avoid loss of precision when squeezing 4 bytes of data into 2 bytes of data?

Comment: To help understand the problem you're trying to solve can you explain why you need to store a float in a short?

Comment: Plus, how are you going to "convert" a floating-point value to a non-floating-point?

Comment: You will need to decide either a certain point to use for the lowest bit, or write some code to store the `float` like the FPU normally does.

Comment: @BackSlash: That's not an issue. If you take an integer of the same size (`int` would do on most platforms) then there's no problem with regards to the type of data. For example, given `float f` and `int i`, you can do `i = *(int*)&f`.

Comment: Impossible. All you will get is zero. The question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @barakmanos I meant, how can you store `0.37885` into a type which doesn't have decimal numbers? All you will get is `0`... Does it make sense?

Comment: @BackSlash: Use `i = *(int*)&f`, and at a later point, use `f = *(float*)&i`. The variable `f` will retain its original value.

Comment: I understand that there will be loss. I have this sine wave which generates values like the one mentioned above, but I want them as shorts. Direct casting with short gives me a value of 0. so what is the solution?

Comment: @barakmanos Did you forget that this is ***java***?

Comment: float has 23 bits of mantissa, how can you fit that into 16 bits, not even counting the extra range due to 8 bits of exponent

Comment: @BackSlash: No, I was careless enough not to notice that, assuming that the question was tagged as C (and you know what they say about the motherhood of assumptions)...

Comment: A sine wave takes values in the range [-1,1]. There are only three values in that range that can be represented in any integer type, -1, 0, and 1.

Comment: @user3840530: I assume you have values between -1 and 1 want to have short integers to turn them into a wave file or pass them to a sound driver. In that case, simply do: `intvalue = floatvalue * 65536.0f - 32768.0f;`. You may have to add code to cut off any excess.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Thanks for the info. I am now scaling them as Short.MaxValue for the android audioTrack sound functinality as it accepts a short buffer for audio playback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static short floatToShort(float x) {
    if (x < Short.MIN_VALUE) {
        return Short.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    if (x > Short.MAX_VALUE) {
        return Short.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    return (short) Math.round(x);
}
```

You'll loose the fractional part:

```
float    4 byte floating-point
double   8 byte floating-point (normal)
short    2 byte integer
int      4 byte integer (normal)
long     8 byte integer
```

***Edit:***

Maybe you wanted to know how to save the bits of a **float** (4 bytes) into an **int** (4 bytes):
(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToRawIntBits(float))

```
float x = 0.1f;
int n = Float.floatToRawIntBits(x);
float y = Float.intBitsToFloat(n);
```

Comment: I agree that there will be loss of precision but all I wanted was a workaround. I will mark this as the answer( if it allows me to).

Comment: Thanks for the Save the bits method. That will be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

In principle, you could just multiply it by 100000, convert it to int, then subtract -32,767 and convert it to short. If that still puts it in the -32,767 to 32,767 range for all your values, that's likely the best you can do. Otherwise, you'll have to limit your precision and multiply by 10000.

And when you use the short of course you have to remember to divide it back down.

Comment: I think that is the *only* correct answer, but assuming his sine wave returns values between -1 and 1 (inclusive), I would multiply them by 65535 and then subtract 32767.

Comment: This won't work. Ex for the value of 1: 1 * 65535 - 32767 = 32768. This is wrong, it is outside of short range. Other example: -1 * 65535 - 32767 will give -98302.

Answer (score 3):

If your input `float` values are in a defined range (for now let's assume they're in the range of `-1..1`, exclusive), you can multiply them to get a value whose fraction you'll throw away.

Valid short range is: `-32768..32767` so you can multiple with `32768` in this case (max short / max input value).

For example:

```
float f = 0.23451f;
short s = (short) (f * 32768);
```

To decode a `short` value to `float`:

```
float f2 = s / 32768f;
```

Answer (score 1):

`short` is an [integral type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1), so it can only contain whole numbers. The only two choices for `0.37885` in a `short` are `0` or `1`, both of which (it seems to me) lose quite a bit of precision.

So the answer is: If you're okay with losing all fractional values, either use a cast, [`Float#shortValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#shortValue--), or [`Math.round(float)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-float-) (and cast the resulting `int` to `short`).

Example: [Live Copy](http://ideone.com/jBUjhW)

```
float f1 = 0.37885f;
short s1 = (short)Math.round(f1);
System.out.println("s1 = " + s1);

float f2 = 27.67885f;
short s2 = (short)Math.round(f2);
System.out.println("s2 = " + s2);
```

Output:

```
s1 = 0
s2 = 28
```

---

In a comment you said:

> I have this sine wave which generates values like the one mentioned above, but I want them as shorts.

Ah, now, we can do something with that. Presumably the values you're getting are all between `0` and `1`. You can store them as shorts by multiplying. Since the range of a `short` is -32,768 to 37,767, a convenient number to multiply them by might be 10000:

```
short s = Math.round(floatValue * 10000);
```

The number we'd get for your example would be `3789`. Example: [Live Copy](http://ideone.com/jHhPyv)

```
float floatValue = 0.37885f;
short s = (short)Math.round((double)floatValue * 10000);
System.out.println("s = " + s);
```

That isn't the *same* value, of course, it's the value multipled by ten thousand, so anywhere you're going to use it, you'd have to allow for that.

Comment: Why is that an issue? If you take an integer of the same size (`int` would do on most platforms) then there's no problem with regards to the type of data. For example, given `float f` and `int i`, you can do `i = *(int*)&f`.

Comment: @barakmanos What is that `&`?

Comment: @barakmanos: This is Java, not C. You could probably do something similar to that in Java as well, but A) `float` and `short` are **not** the same size, and B) It's *extremely* unlikely that the OP wants the `short` (or `int`) view of the bits that made up the `float`. :-)

Comment: Ooops, sorry (@BackSlash - same apology to you) ... :)

Comment: @barakmanos funny, you know that just stores the bits, but the mathematical value then is totally different. Java has [Float.floatToRawIntBits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToRawIntBits(float))

Comment: @JoopEggen: 1. In my answer I was referring to C/C++ (my mistake). 2. If you consider storing that value for later use, and for some reason you want to store it in an integer-type value, then you can simply "store the bits" in an `int`. Once you read them back into a `float`, it will retain its original (floating-point) value.